# Resolve a promise array with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to resolve a promise array to `things` before hitting my controller:

```
resolve:{
  things: function($q){
    var promises = [];
    var titles = [];
    var thingRef = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    angular.forEach(thingRefs, function(thingRef){
      promises.push($firebase(ref.child('things').child(thingRef).child('title')).then(function(title){
        titles.push(title);
      }));
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(function(){
      return titles;
    });
  }
},
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
return $q.all(promises).then(function(){
  return titles;
});
```

Because without that outer return the inner return doesn't go anywhere.

Now `resolve.things` returns a promise, that when resolved, will contain an Array of titles.

---

With some other adjustments:

```
resolve:{
  things: function($q){
    var promises = [];
    var thingRef = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
    angular.forEach(thingRefs, function(thingRef){
      promises.push($firebase(ref.child('things').child(thingRef).child('title')));
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
  }
}
```

Comment: I made some additional adjustments. If this doesn't work can you show me the output of the promise and the result of `$firebase(ref.child('things').child(thingRef).child('title'))`?

Comment: I was being completely retarded. I forgot to inject `ref`. Thanks for your help! --- btw you do need the `return` in front of `$q.all()`

Comment: Yes because `$q.all` produce a new promise that gets resolved when all the input promises are resolved. If you don't return anything you just get `undefined`.